# Why does the copy speed decrease for a single file?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, usb-drive, file-copy, nautilus

When copying a 2 GB file from HDD to USB stick, the initial speed is about 80 MB/sec, and decreases steadily to 10 MB/sec or even less.

Why is this so? The answers I've found says it's related to cache. But if the file is being copied only once, what does the cache have to do with it? I thought cache was used for information copied more than once.

I'm using Nautilus on Debian/Gnome, if it makes a difference.

EDIT - Adding some benchmarks

Before copying a 2.4 GB mp4 file, I repeatedly ran some checksums on it, to see how long it takes only to read the file, and also expecting to put it on the disk cache:

```
sha512sum file.mp4 (3x)
19s
8s
6s

sha256sum file.mp4 (3x)
10s
10s
10s

sha512sum file.mp4 (3x)
6s
6s
6s
```

It seems the file went to cache.

Next, I copied it to the USB stick. The default mounting on Debian 10 is asynchronous. The amount copied each minute, the remaining time and the overall speed were:

```
few sec 985 MB  13sec left  116 MB/s
1min    1.1 GB  1 min left  18.6 MB/s
2min    1.4 GB  1 min left  11.7 MB/s
3min    1.7 GB  1 min left  9.7 MB/s
4min    2.1 GB  35sec left  8.7 MB/s
4min45  "done"
eject
(it doesn't inform how long it will take)
+2min22 "ejecting" = ~7min total

2403758161÷427 = 5629410.2 = 5.63 MB/s = 5.37 MiB/s
```

Then I mounted the USB stick with the option `-sync`, and registered the same info each minute:

```
few sec         20min left  2 MB/s
30s             9 min left  3.9 MB/s
1min    272 MB  7 min left  4.5 MB/s
2min    500 MB  7 min left  4.2 MB/s
3min    744 MB  6 min left  4.1 MB/s
4min    1.1 GB  5 min left  4.4 MB/s
5min    1.4 GB  3 min left  4.6 MB/s
6min    1.7 GB  2 min left  4.6 MB/s
7min    2.0 GB  1 min left  4.6 MB/s
8min    2.3 GB  36sec left  4.7 MB/s
8m26s   done

eject
instantaneous

2403758161÷506 = 4750510.2 = 4.75 MB/s = 4.53 MiB/s
```

Conclusions:

The checksum indicates that the time to copy the file to memory is much smaller than the total copy time. So it seems incorrect to use it as part of the overall speed estimation.

Synchronous copy seems to be a little slower, but at least it correctly informs the time remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The HDD is much faster than the USB stick, so when the file is read from the HDD it goes into the cache to free the HDD up for other tasks.  The data is then sent to the USB stick at a speed it can handle.

Cache's are used for files that are referenced more than once, but that's not their only purpose.  At some point, as in this case, the file has to be read for the first time.  Now, if you were to copy the same file again pretty soon, the cache would deliver it instead of the HDD.  After a short while of not being referenced again, the file would be purged from the cache, allowing the cache to handle new data.

Comment: If the USB stick is the limiting speed, still it makes no sense to watch a continuously decreasing copy speed. The speed should be, all the time, the USB speed.

Comment: Even if Nautilus is showing the average speed between copy/paste, we should have only two phases (copy from cache vs. copy from HDD), since the cache size is much smaller than 2 GB. Instead, the decrease in speed seems to be linear.

Comment: @Rodrigo the overall speed will be at most that of USB. It will start fast, because of the cache. How slowly it goes to the actual USB speed depends on many system factors, among them the way your application calculates data transfers and how often things are actually written to USB. Depending on the size, you could have an instantaneous transfer, but then have to write the transfer time when you want to eject the drive (because only then the system might transfer the data).

Comment: @Rodrigo You may be confusing CPU cache with disk cache. The latter can use almost all available RAM -- certainly much more than 2GB even on my Laptop. `mount` does have a `-sync` option, but I would expect serious impact on throughput.

Comment: @Rodrigo - also, it's not just an average - it's an *average over time*. So, the speed will decrease in a linear manner until such time as the average reaches the maximum speed that the USB can handle - or slightly above that and possibly/probably rounded to the nearest x%. Decreasing in a linear fashion would be the expected result if it's an average over time.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I see so many wrong things there! If the limiting speed is the USB's, then why periods of non-write? Doesn't it only slower things down? And why in the world only copy when I ask for eject? If I find a switch to avoid all this and simply write directly to USB, I'd surely try it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Do you have a reference for this? The references I'm seeing talk of a 8-256 MB disk cache, as well as ctrl-alt-delor's answer ("Soon you run out of cache/write-buffer"). It would be great to add this option (-sync) to Debian USB automount. But I'll do some measurements with it.

Comment: @Rodrigo That's yet another kind of cache -- it's a very generic term. In 1968, we called it "double buffering" -- even things like punch-card readers and line printers could do autonomous actions while your code ran. Any modern disk will have an inbuilt cache so that it does not need dedicated access to the host connection and the magnetic media simultaneously. However, the RAM cache we refer to in Linux shows up in `top` as buff/cache, and serves all processes and all devices to minimise wait times globally. It uses an left-over memory. See `linuxatemyram.com`

Answer (score 0):

Data will be written to cache/write-buffer, this happens fast. Then it is copied out to the secondary-storage device (the USB), this happens more slowly. Soon you run out of cache/write-buffer, at this point writes to cache/write-buffer reduces to the write speed of the secondary-storage (USB).

You can do the copy with no caching. The main benefit of this is that other (possibly more important) data is not dropped from the cache.